# problems with wordpress installation

Tags: wordpress

**I am helping out a NGO as a volunteer to:**
- *recover their website, after an incident with their web hosting service (internal sabotage by someone who left the organization).*
- *I shall notice that they even had not access to the source, which makes things even more difficult;*

**Here’s what I did:**
- *installed mamp my Macintosh*
 
- *to make things easy and being really quick I developed a minimal website in Wordpress with their content in less then a couple of hours*
- *I asked them to get a new web domain (they were also sabotaged in the domain)*
- *I called a friend who runs an IT company to give us a free web hosting service, which is already mapped to the new domain*
- *I shall notice that the new domain doesn’t have the dns mapped to the web hosting service*

**Regarding migration:**
- *by now, I will have to run the website using the*
 
- _I first tried to backup my data from mamp into the ftp public_html server it’s running panel, as well as cloning the database and migrating it)_
- *I could not access the Wordpress installation via the IP address*

**As the first website iteration is pretty minimal, it’s done, and I can basically migrate the contents pretty easily after installing Wordpress:**
- *I erased the previous installation in their database*
- _I cloned a blank Wordpress copy into public_html/site (where site replaces Wordpress_
- *I crated a database in mysql as well as a user, and I associated the user with the database*
- *I editing the wp-config.php file, and added in database name, user, password*

**I added in a couple fields near the end of the document with:**
- define('WP_HOME','http://ip/~user_name’);
- define('WP_SITEURL','http://ip/~user_name');

**After that I tried to access the website via http://ip/~user_name where:**
- _the ip argument and the ~user_name is replaced by the proper values_
- *it didn’t work out*

**I also tried:**
- *Ipaddress/site/wp-admin*
- *it didn’t workout*

**I appreciate all the possible help as:**
- *this must be done by tomorrow*

**I shall notice that:**
- *the web hosting service is not really co-operating with giving technical assistance*

Comment: Unfortunately StackOverflow isn't the place for a generic set of issues like this. There's no programming question. But more importantly: The reasoning (internal sabotage) doesn't matter, and the timing (must be done by tomorrow) really doesn't matter here, as this isn't a paid-consulting type of thing - this is just a place for volunteers to answer programming questions. No such thing as urgency here.

Comment: Also, I can't imagine how anyone here can help you recover your data - that's going to be between you and the hosting company.

Comment: i already have a website done in localhost. just asking help migrating it

Comment: Lots and lots of documentation exists on the web about migrating WordPress sites.Again, off-topic here (documentation/tutorial recommendations are expressly off-topic).

Comment: and i have followed that documentation, without proper results

Comment: dear David Makogon. I have a really big sense of respect for yur work (the fact that you work for microsoft, and your stackoverflow rank is pretty self-explanatory, doesn't need much more). if you don't have time or availability to help me with this, please don't make things harder for me, as i am here to support a noble environmental cause

Comment: Hi Tiago - I'm not trying to make things harder for you, and I've done my fair share (and still do) with such organizations. I'm just saying that you won't be able to get the help you need here. At least not how things are written up. And I'm trying to explain to you that, even if you have a crisis needing immediate assistance, you cannot ever assume StackOverflow will provide a timely answer. For such crises, it's best to hire someone. Anyway... that's about all I can say at this point.

Comment: don't worry i have some friends why i trust in, that have 12+-16+ years of experience in IT, some of them with masters and phds in computer science who may be willing to help. it's just that i wasn't able of getting in touch yet with them, once today is like sunday. but i understand your insights and i will be doing my best to fix this

Answer (score 0):

**the problem was really, really simple:**

- *when evoking ip/~username i was using the name of the database in username rather then the name of the webhosting account. now everything is working.*

<sub>**thank you anyway**</sub>